# Python: how to append an empty row in a cycle with try-except

Tags: python-3.x, api, for-loop, try-catch

This is my actual function:

```
def Function(con):
    details = []
    for ID in con:
        print(ID)
        try:
            req = requests.get('https://XYZ').json()['Data']
            details.append(req)
        except:
            pass
    return pd.DataFrame(details)
```

Since many data are missing during the download, I created a try-except to manage possible errors and keep the cycle going on.

The problem is that in this way many rows are completely skipped and I cannot figure out anymore which line is associated with which `ID` (of `con`) used as an input.

Two possible solution in my book:

1. Append a zero row when the cycle pass
2. Keep track, during the cycle, the `ID`s by appending a `ID` column

Can you help me?

Comment: Option 1 of "your book" would be a mere `details.append(None)` or so instead of the `pass` in your code. Where's the problem?

Comment: You can also choose `details.append([])`. I think it is more explicit that it is a zero row element vice `NoneType`. Other than that, you've missed a closing `'` in your `get()`.

Comment: I dont know, maybe there are in fact actual rows with zero columns (and no exception in the request). Then `None` would be more explicit.

Comment: Thank you everybody (also for the missing `'`)!